# Form validation returns non-unique slug error after edit()

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm having an issue with a module that I am writing (Shop-products module).

When I run form validation once, everything is fine. However when I `edit()` the product and run the validation runs again (which is what I expect) but it returns an error saying that the slug must be unique.

**How can I change the validation rule for the edit mode to ignore checking the existing row/field?**

Below is a subset of my controller class:

```
public function create() {
    //this works fine
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('slug', 'Slug',
     'trim|required|is_unique[shop_products.slug]');    

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) { }
}

//when this runs the validation for slug returns saying not unique
// do i need a different validation rule ??

public function edit($id = 0) {
    $this->data = $this->products_m->get($id);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('slug', 'Slug',
     'trim|required|is_unique[shop_products.slug]');    

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) { }
}
```

Comment: What does `edit()` do?

Comment: sorry, its the edit function on my products controller

Comment: yes how do I still have the validation rule for editing but set it  to ignor the record with id=??

Answer (score 4):

its because you've saved the `slug` in your DB and upon editing it. it returns an error because its referring to itself. you can try to make a `call_back function` upon updating your new value, that function then connects to the model and runs a query checking the new value. You can try something like this:

---

**UPDATE**
you should never update the **ID** especially if its a `primary key - auto increment` you can just use it to find the specific slug that is to be updated, you can check the `slug` uniqueness but not the `id if its the primary key`

```
public function check_slug()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $data = array('id' => $id);
    if($this->model->check_slug($data))     
        return false;
    else
        return true;
    // end if
} // end function

public function update_slug_valiation()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $slug = $this->input-->post('slug');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('slug', 'Slug', 'callback_check_slug');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE)
    {
        $data = array('slug' => $slug);
        if($this->model->update_slug($data))
        {
            echo "<script> alert('Slug Updated!'); </script>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script> alert('Updating Failed!'); </script>";
        }
        //end if
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Slug is already taken'); </script>";
    }
    // end if
} // end function
```